# Postback causes whitescreen when posting data to url containing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback, fatal-error

I have encountered an unexpected behaviour and/or bug in the .net postback system.

I have a page that uses a master page to provide common elements, with form inputs split between the child and master pages. The form submit button is located on the master page, and I am attempting to process postback on the masterpage.

Any time I attempt to submit data where the form contains any non empty values **and** the url contains parameters, the page fails to process correctly. This does not occur if the page is submitted under either condition by itself.

The form postback method is post.

The page fails to load and in firefox returns the no element found error.

I have checked for correct class names ect and I do have empty attributes in non form elements, but as the page loads correctly at first I don't think that is relevant. I have also checked for infinately looping code.

This is the current postback handling code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        save_page();
    }

    page_render();
}

//save
private void save_page()
{
    dev_text.Text = "save in progress";
}
```

Comment: What is `page_render` doing?  My guess is that you're trying to send back to the browser "save in progress" at the start of the request while the save takes place.  If that is the case, then instead of trying to set the text from the server side, consider setting it using client-side script at the moment of submission

Comment: @freefaller page_render does little more than run and display an sql query. Also that save_page function isn't turnicated, that is literally as far as I am. Also I have just tried commenting out the save in progress line which has not helped.

Comment: I'm in the middle of writing an answer based on whether you are trying to display "saving in progress" to the user... is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: OK, in that case my answer might not be that useful to you. See if it does... otherwise I'm not sure there is enough information in your question to answer you

Answer (score 0):

Setting text in an HTML element on the server will only be seen on the browser when the HTML is sent to the browser. Normally this happens once the entire processing of the page has completed... so normally quite some time after the user initiated the post-back.

Instead of setting the text on the server, consider setting the text directly on the browser at the moment of submission.  Something like...

```
function setSavingText(){
   // Vanilla javascript...
   document.getElementById("<%=dev_text.ClientId%>").innerHTML = "save in progress";
   // JQuery...
   $("#<%=dev_text.ClientId%>").text("save in progress");
}

<asp:Button runat="server" ... OnClientClick="setSavingText();" />
```

The above function contains both a line for vanilla (normal) javascript, and one for the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com). You only need **one** of them.